# Purging process of a rocket engine

Tags: spacex, propulsion, landing, reuse, engines

Does spacex purge Falcon 9 engines after landing ? If so, which gas is used for purging?

Comment: I am just guessing: Spacex might have a lot of on-board RCS’s gas which might come handy or use a dedicated N2 bottle. Or they may purge during post landing checks.